# CASE statement logic in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

I am working on SQL Server 2014 and I am struggling with coming up with CASE statement logic to alter the DisciplinaryActionReasonCode value to the record with a "seq" number of 1 when the permnum, DisciplinaryIncidentNumber and DateofDisciplinaryAction values are duplicated.  What I have in my SQL code below is what I've attempted.  You'll see that in the image I've attached I am needing to change the 41 value to 21 based on what I've stated above.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is my SQL code:

```
DECLARE @SchoolYear varchar(4) = '2016'
DECLARE @Submission int = 3;

SELECT @SchoolYear as SchoolYear, 
    @Submission AS Submission, 
    '220905' AS DistrictID, 
    Row_number() OVER (partition by A.incnum, A.locid ORDER BY A.dispnum DESC) as seq,
    A.permnum, 
    B.txuniqueid, 
    '220905' + A.disschnum AS CampusIDofEnrollment, 
    stuff(A.incnum, 1, 0, replicate('0', 6 - len(A.incnum))) AS DisciplinaryIncidentNumber,
    **CASE 
        WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.incnum, A.locid ORDER BY A.dispnum DESC) > 2     
        AND COUNT(A.PERMNUM) > 1
        AND COUNT(STUFF(A.incnum, 1, 0, REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(A.incnum)))) > 1
        AND COUNT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.dateofdisciplinaryaction, 120) > 1
        THEN 

        --WHEN A.desccode LIKE 'XSTA-[0-9][0-9]%' THEN Substring(A.desccode, 6, 2) ELSE Substring(A.desccode, 1, 2) 
    END AS DisciplinaryActionReasonCode,**
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.dateofdisciplinaryaction, 120) AS DateofDisciplinaryAction 
FROM [dbo].[XXdiscipline] A 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[XXstudents] B 
ON A.permnum = B.permnum 
WHERE (A.desccode LIKE '[0-9][0-9]%' OR A.desccode LIKE 'XSTA%') 
AND (A.dispcode LIKE '[0-9][0-9]%' OR A.dispcode LIKE 'XSTA-[0-9][0-9]%') 
AND A.PERMNUM = 1042003
ORDER BY permnum asc, DisciplinaryIncidentNumber asc,  a.DISPNUM asc
```

Here is an image of the SQL results:  [image: CaseStatememtLogicQuestion]

Comment: Is the Row_Number...=2 part for testing purposes or is that part of the logic? What if row number=3?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. But you might read this before continuing alias a,b,c...https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys.  The ROW_NUMBER should read > 1 I'll make that correction.

Comment: Bottom line, from the PIC I attached, the 41 value in the DisciplinaryActionReasonCode column needs to reflect 21 where the record that has a SEQ number value that has a 1.  Hope that helps.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks Sean.  Is my PIC not seen?

Comment: FWIW I understand the requirements but I do agree they could be a bit clearer. Do any of those fields have nulls? For troubleshooting, perhaps make each of your count statements their own column to test and see what you are getting for results (I do this a lot with CASE statements).

Comment: Yes we can see your image...but an image does not let others write some code to help you. I think you are wanting to get the action reson for seq 1 when the seq is > 1??

Comment: Correct.  I thought putting the SQL code in this post would help.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you even need the Row_Number line at all? Won't evaluating your 3 counts suffice? I have a feeling that is throwing this off.

Comment: Yes, I am needing the Row_Number logic. But if I didn't need it I'm still not sure how to get the THEN logic to reflect the other disciplinaryactionreasoncode value that I'm needing.

Comment: What you say you need in your question text "permnum, DisciplinaryIncidentNumber and DateofDisciplinaryAction values are duplicated", and what you say in your sql `PARTITION BY A.incnum, A.locid ... COUNT(A.PERMNUM) ... COUNT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.dateofdisciplinaryaction, 120) > 1` differs. Please decide what are your criteria for determining a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your case statement, based on what you've said in your text question body on how you determine a duplicate:

```
CASE 
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.incnum, A.dateofdisciplinaryaction, A.permnum ORDER BY A.dispnum DESC) = 1     
    THEN 21
    ELSE 41
END AS DisciplinaryActionReasonCode,
```

(If your 21 and 41 are supposed to be the other way round, swap them over)

(Actually, your spec doesn't make much sense, because you've showed us a column of mainly 21, but one row of 41, and youre saying you want to change the code from 41 to 21, but that's just a simple `21 as DisciplinaryReasonCode`)

Comment: Thanks, I wish it was that easy.  The value may not always be 21 or 41.

Comment: Sadly, my crystal ball doesn't work too well these days; you'll need to state where to get the 21, 41 or OTHER_NUMBER from if you want help with that... But it's not too hard, just substitute 21, 41 etc with a column name or formula that calculates/provides the new code

Comment: Thanks Caius.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi guys, my apologies for all the confusion.  I appreciated your time in responding and help in communicating more clearly next time.  I was finally able to resolve my issue with temp tables.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In getting some help from a user in another forum, I found that the CASE statement was NOT the fix that I had hoped for.  I created a CTE statement of my SQL code and then was able to query the correct results using the FIRST_VALUE function built into SQL Server which is what Luis at SQL Server Central suggested.  Here is the final fix and hopefully it will help someone else:

```
SELECT SchoolYear, Submission, DistrictID, PERMNUM, DisciplinaryIncidentNumber, FIRST_VALUE(DisciplinaryActionReasonCode) OVER(PARTITION BY SchoolYear, Submission, DistrictID, PERMNUM ORDER BY seq) as DisciplinaryActionReasonCode
FROM CTE1
ORDER BY PERMNUM asc, DisciplinaryIncidentNumber asc, DisciplinaryActionReasonCode asc;
```